# Grunt - Get variable exported in the environemnt to string in a file

Tags: angularjs, node.js, gruntjs

Hi I would like  to do a simple task:

export a variable in linux:

```
export API = "http://127.0.0.1:999"
```

then get it with grunt script.

And replace a row inside my apiService.

currently i wasn't able to console.log the environment variable:

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {
  grunt.initConfig({
    pkg: grunt.file.readJSON('package.json'),
    destination: process.env.API,

  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-envpreprocess');
  grunt.registerTask('default',['watch']);

  console.log("here: " + process.env.API);
};
```

Can  someone help me figure out how to do that?

THanks

Answer (score 0):

you did not close curly bracket (LN5), try something like this:

```
const grunt = require('grunt');

module.exports = function(grunt) {
  grunt.initConfig({
    pkg: grunt.file.readJSON('package.json'),
    destination: process.env.API || 'none',
  });

  grunt.registerTask('default', () => {
    console.log("here: ", grunt.config.get('destination'));
  });  
};
```

Comment: This is not the issue